# Starting a big shop with Drupal Commerce (I don't wanna use Magento)

Tags: drupal-commerce

I want to start a big shop... Too many products, detailed catalog, more power with attributes handling, fast, easy to extend and so on... and I don't want to use Magento for this. I don't have any experience with Drupal and its extensions, I'm extremely new to it. All I ask is... "is Drupal (Drupal Commerce or others) the thing I'm looking for?"

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about Magento, but I am familiar to Drupal. A Shopping site CAN be implemented easily with Drupal.

If you are planning to use Drupal, then I would suggest you to use Drupal Commerce. The two main modules used for the shopping cart are Drupal commerce and Ubercart. Ubercart has actually no "relation" with Drupal, but is actually more "experienced" than Drupal commerce.
But Drupal commerce, on the other hand, is the commerce module of Drupal. We can customize the options provided by this module in any way. Drupal commerce definitelys is more extensive than ubercart. But when it comes to the payment integration and all, Ubercart has much more to provide than Drupal commerce.

Good luck with your site.

Answer (score 0):

Try OpenCart. Drupal is not best solution for big shop.
OpenCart have very easy product options, attributes, multilangs...  Drupal Commerce and UberCart take much more time for for same functionality.